# How multi select in a Select?

Tags: oracle, select

i'm a lost in this case.

I want to do a SELECT  with two select in. Is that possible? 
I've already try UNION. Do you have any idea ? :(

Here is my quest : (SQL - ORACLE)

```
SELECT 
    PCTX_LA0,
    PCTX_LA1,
    PCTX_LA3,
    PCTX_LA2_LA4,
    PCTX_LA5,
    CTX_ACTION1,
    CTX_ACTION2,
    CTX_DATE
FROM (
    --Précontentieux
    SELECT     
        CASE KLIGCONT.COENTAC WHEN 'LA0' THEN KLIGCONT.CODSIT ELSE NULL END AS PCTX_LA0,
        CASE KLIGCONT.COENTAC WHEN 'LA1' THEN KLIGCONT.CODSIT ELSE NULL END AS PCTX_LA1,
        CASE KLIGCONT.COENTAC WHEN 'LA3' THEN KLIGCONT.CODSIT ELSE NULL END AS PCTX_LA3,
        CASE KLIGCONT.COENTAC WHEN 'LA2' THEN KLIGCONT.CODSIT WHEN 'LA4' THEN KLIGCONT.CODSIT ELSE NULL END AS PCTX_LA2_LA4,
        CASE KLIGCONT.COENTAC WHEN 'LA5' THEN KLIGCONT.CODSIT ELSE NULL END AS PCTX_LA5
    FROM LOGI.KLIGCONT KLIGCONT
    WHERE KLIGCONT.COPROC='BOBS'
    AND KLIGCONT.COVALID='O'   


    --Contentieux
    SELECT    
        KLIGCONT.COENTAC AS CTX_ACTION1,
        KCOENTAC.COLIBEVE AS CTX_ACTION2,
        KLIGCONT.CODSIT AS CTX_DATE
    FROM 
        LOGI.KLIGCONT KLIGCONT,
        LOGI.KCOENTAC KCOENTAC 
    WHERE KLIGCONT.SCSO = KCOENTAC.SCSO 
    AND KLIGCONT.COENTAC = KCOENTAC.COENTAC
    AND KLIGCONT.COPROC='COMM'
    AND KLIGCONT.COVALID='O'
   )
```

Thx in advice..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each query retrieves one row only:

```
select 
    a.col1,
    a.col2,
    a.col3,
    b.col1,
    b.col2,
    b.col3
from (
       select col1, col2, col3 from a_table
     ) a,
     (
       select col1, col2, col3 from b_table
     ) b
```

Otherwise, you'll need to join a to b somewhere in the outer query's `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    col1,
    col2,
    col3,
    col4,
    col5,
    col6
from (
       select col1, col2, col3 from a_table
     ) ,
     (
       select col4, col5, col6 from b_table
     )
```

THIS CODE TEST , OK